# How to make robust assert?

Tags: c++, assert

I want to realize this behavior:

- When program runs in debug mode, `assert_robust(expression, commands)` works strictly like classical `assert(expression)`
- When program runs in release mode, `assert_robust(expression, commands)` perform some `commands` if expression is false

This can be done this way:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
    #define assert_robust(expression, command) if (!(expression)) command;
#else
    #define assert_robust(expression, command) assert(expression); 
#endif
```

And this can be used for example this way to make `myfunction` fault-tolerant:

```
char myfunction(const string& s, int i)
{
    assert_robust(i >= 0, return '\0');

    /* Normal code */
}
```

This work well, but how to make macro `assert_robust` that supports more than one (arbitrary) number of commands? (preferably by a standard C++ way)

**And another question is:**

Is it good thing to be strict in debug and benevolent in release?

**EDIT:** My idea why do such a thing is because it is practicaly much better if it is a bug in the program that the program maintains sometimes a little weird than when it crashes and user losing their data.

Comment: That sounds a lot like trying to use asserts for error handling... (which is not a Good Idea TM)

Comment: @Xarn: Can you explain why it's not good idea?

Comment: Asserts are usually meant to be used by a programmer to check his own work, where error handling (return codes, exceptions, errno) are meant to provide checks for public API. (Assertions basically document what you think of as logically impossible execution states, and as such you shouldn't trip them. Exceptions say that someone else messed up.)

Comment: Another way to look at it: Assertions are for detecting when you, the programmer, messed up. Exceptions (or whatever is used in place of them) are for when the user of your program messes up. You shouldn't have any of your initial mistakes leaking out into release mode. Your users won't even have a chance at making a mistake until you do a release. Programmer errors and user errors are completely orthogonal to one another.

Comment: Check the Eiffel documentation about "Check" for an explanation: http://docs.eiffel.com/book/method/et-instructions#Check

Answer (score 3):

The more interesting question is the second:

> Is it good thing to be strict in debug and benevolent in release?

My experiences is that it is a horrible idea to have different behavior in debug and release builds. You are signing up for issues in production that you will never be able to reproduce in a debug build because the behavior of the two is different.

Other than that, which you may claim won't be an issue if you assert in the first place in debug mode, asserts should be used to flag programming issues, situations from which you cannot recover safely. If you can recover safely in release mode, why assert in DEBUG? If you cannot, are you willing to fiddle with production data in a way you don't quite understand what it will do?

Comment: "If you can recover safely in release mode, why assert in DEBUG?"

Maybe you are right. I donť know it exactly, i have intuition that what i want to do its good thing. :-) But also there is interesting analogy:  
Writers of some file format strictly respects specification of that format.
But readers are more benevolent and fault tolerant - and thats good.

Comment: @user3123061: But either the reader can recover from the error or it cannot. If you think you can recover, you should attempt to recover both in debug and release modes as that is the only way that you can sanely test the recovery. What you are saying here is that you want to debug an application, and then run a similar but different one in production.

Comment: I dont think i can recover here. If something gives me negative index, i dont know why. Thats type of error that must not happen. But if happen yet, then in debug i want to program stops and i look into stack trace to find origin of bug. But in release i do not want to user pay taxes, be distracted some error listing and crashes for my easier debuging life. Bug in my program is my problem, no user problem. I and not user must work hard to find whats problem. Helping me to debug program simply is not user job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think to use assertions this way is a good idea. Usually you use an assert, if you want the predicate to be always true, because its part of critical code. If its not true, than there is obviously a big problem and aborting is reasonable. But more and more people use assert like an ordinary error check for debugging. In this case its adequate to disable it completely in release mode. It think you should decide for one of this two approaches.

But if you want to run some kind of emergency commands before aborting, you could use the new lambda functions from C++11:

```
void ASSERT(int expression, std::function<void()> func) {
    if(!expression) {
        if (func) func();
        abort();
    }
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
ASSERT(a >= 0, []() { std::cerr << "ERROR" << std::endl;});
```

Or:

```
ASSERT(a >= 0, [this]() { this->terminate(); });
```

Or:

```
ASSERT(a >= 0, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the issue of if this is a good idea or not, you can use your macro to wrap multiple commands in a `do-while(0);` loop.

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
    #define assert_robust(expression, command) if (!(expression)) \
                                                 do{command;} while(0)
#else
    #define assert_robust(expression, command) assert(expression)
#endif
```

Note also that I did not include semicolons at the ends of the macros. If you include them in the macros, then something like

```
assert_robust(cond1, command1) /* no semicolon here, no problem */
assert_robust(cond2, command2) /* no semicolon here, no problem */
```

would be allowed, which would be really weird.